# How to override "action" of a form?

Tags: forms

after a form submission I want to redirect to an url. The "action" attribute of the form is `['#action']=homepage`. How can I override this?

I have used this code

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {  
  if ($form_id=='views-exposed-form-job-search-search-page') {
    global $base_url;
    $form['#action'] = $base_url.'/search/job'; 
  }
}
```

However it doesn't work, it still redirects me to /homepage. What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Just to double check, did you clear the cache after adding your hook_form_alter?

Comment: Hi,yep I have cleared caches.

Comment: Can you confirm your hook_form_alter is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$form_id` argument is the internal form ID, not the CSS ID. For views exposed forms it'll always be `views_exposed_form`.

I think this is the easiest way to target a specific exposed form:

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $view = $form_state['view'];
  if ($view->name == 'foo' && $view->current_display == 'bar') {
    // Alter the form...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I had to change the form_id,I was using the CSS form id.